# discard values from file given a condition

Tags: awk

I have file1 with two columns and for each line, I only want to print (in another file, file2) the value of the 2nd column if the first one satisfies a condition, for example

```
-0.02  12  
2 54
```

if the condition is absolute value <0.03 i'll get
-`0.02 12`

Comment: `awk '$1<0.03 && $1>-0.03'` should do the trick

Comment: or `awk '$1^2<0.03^2'`

Comment: You SAY you `only want to print .. the value of the 2nd column` but then your expected output shows both columns `-0.02 12` - what do you really want?

Answer (score 1):

`awk` doesn't have the absolute value function but you can easily add it.

```
$ awk 'function abs(x) {return x>0?x:-x} abs($1)<0.03'
```

or use the definition in the condition (as in @Nevill's comment)

```
$ awk '$1<0.03 && $1>-0.03'
```

or, use math to further simplify to

```
$ awk '$1^2<0.03^2`
```